# How we can show scrollbar if max index exceeded in highcharts timeline?

Tags: highcharts

I have data like this:
[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuqevn41/)

```
 xAxis: {
                        max: length < 10 ? length-1 : 10,
                        scrollbar: {
                            enabled: length < 10 ? false : true
                        },
                        type: 'category',
                        style:{
                            fontSize: '11px',
                        }
                    },
```

I have tried this to show scroll bar on x-axis if my max size exceeded but this not worked for me. Can you help me out to show the scroll bar if the max size is exceeded?

reference:[Js fiddle scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oy1xLkc5/)

Not exactly the above scroll normal scroll bar also help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `scrollbar.enabled` option dependent on `data.length` in the below way.

Please note that the `scrollbar` feature is only available in Highstock.

```
scrollbar: {
    enabled: data.length < 10 ? false : true
},
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pe7kcsjL/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/scrollbar.enabled